# Assembly x86 read a string character by character

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I'm getting as input a string of numbers, i'd like to read it character by character in order to convert each digit in integer.

Example input: 54321

i need to convert it to the numeric value 54321 to make some operation.

This is the function i'm using to read

```
STRING                      DB      20,0 
                            RESB    20

   ;;;;;;;;;   Code here   ;;;;;;;;;

    MOV                     DX,STRING
    MOV                     AH,0Ah
    INT                                     21h
```

At least if you can tell me the logic or a function for 8086 useful to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is only an array. So the first letter is for example in "edx" the second letter in "edx+1" the third letter in "edx+2" and so on..

You can convert the characters back to integers with this calculation:

'chardigit' - 48 = integerdigit

this is possible because ascii '0' is 48. Here is an example:

```
"123"

'1' (or 49 in dec) - 48 = 1
'2' (or 50 in dec) - 48 = 2
'3' (or 51 in dec) - 48 = 3
```

I hope this is intelligible.

Comment: Using this dos call (INT 21H, the 21H not showing in the post), STRING+1 will contain the number of characters entered (not including the return key), and the entered data will start at STRING+2.

Comment: Yes i edited the 21h :) So in this case i gotta check my number from `STRING+2` till `STRING+22` because `STRING` size is 20? And if my number is `1234` in `STRING+2` i'm going to find 1 or 4?

Comment: Those decimal values are using the base ten number system.

Comment: @obiWanKeNerd you are going to find 1 and yes string+2 - string+22 is your string